# MATLAB programming for steganography

Tags: matlab

1. How to change the data type while using mat2cell function from double to logical?
2. I have bit plane spliced the gray image and have done some manipulations. Whats the code to combine the planes get back the manipulated image?

Both related to MATLAB

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To answer your first question you call `logical`, then `mat2cell` to obtain a cell array of logicals.  For example:

```
x = [1 3 4 5 0 1];
mat2cell(logical(x)', [1,1,1,1])
ans = 
{
  [1,1] =  1
  [2,1] =  1
  [3,1] =  1
  [4,1] =  1
  [5,1] = 0
  [6,1] =  1
}
```

I'm not sure I understand your second question. It would depend on what manipulations you've done to the original image.

Comment: I have replaced some of the cells for the cells of the secret image. After all manipulations I will have 8 planes of size 512x512. I have to combine them to form a single image; containing 8 bits in each pixel.